# Find out all members of a set.

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the set $F=\{f:\mathbb C\rightarrow \mathbb C\mid f \text{ is an entire function, } |f'(z)|\le|f(z)| \text{ for all } z\in\mathbb C\}$.
Then find out all members of $F.$

My Attempt: I have observed that $ae^{bz}$ where $a\in\mathbb C,$ $b\in\mathbb C,$ $|b|\le1$, are members of $F.$
But I'm not sure that they are all members of $F.$
Also my approach is only example based. 
Please give me a better approach to solve this problem.